# How can I add a new address line within moderncv style

Tags: moderncv, addresses

I'd like to have 3 lines for address with moderncv style.
So I've added this lines in my file

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\address}[3]{\def\@addressstreet{#1}\def\@addresscity{#2}\def\@addresscountry{#3}}
\makeatother

\address{Street }{town}{Country}
```

but nothing has changed.
Can anybody tell me how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to simply use multi-line arguments, i.e. `\address{Street}{Town\\Country}`.

Your definition doesn't work, because `\address` only stores the information. The actual printing is done by the `\maketitle` command, which is redefined in the corresponding `.sty` file, i.e. `moderncvthemeclassic.sty`.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. I get this error message "!Argument of \@firstoftow has an extra"

Comment: I would correct here, using multi-line arguments is allowed only for the first one `\address{Street\\Town}{Country}`

Answer (score 8):

`moderncv` has changed its syntax again so my old answer no longer works for a number of reasons.  Anyway things are now much simpler because version `2.0.0` of `moderncv` now provides a command `\makenewline` that can be inserted in to the arguments of `\address`.  Thus you can write

```
\address{street and number}{postcode city\makenewline county\makenewline country}
```

to place several arguments in the second part.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{John}{Doe}

\address{street and number}{postcode city\makenewline
county\makenewline country} 

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```